# import files containing the positive and negative words into R

Tags: r, twitter, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to do **sentiment analysis** on tweets ( I have a dataset with tweets, so no API scraping) in order to see if a tweet is negative or positive. I downloaded a list of negative and positive words. They are saved as a textfile in my working directory with the exact same name as in the code below. However, this code gives my an error:

```
positive_words <- readLines("positive_words.txt")
```

> *Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message: In file(con, "r") :   cannot open file
>   'positive_words.txt': No such file or directory*

How can I import these textfiles into R?

Thank you!!

Comment: You can use `list.files()` to check if the file is actually in your working directory.

Comment: and in addition to what @Psidom just said, make sure you have the correct file name. If the file name is correct, you can use `getwd()` to see if you are in the correct directory, if not: `setwd(your/directory/path)`

Comment: Psidom and Bas, thank you!! Was indeed not in my working directory :) It is working now!